# How can I make a conditional reduce call for an array of objects in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the numbers array which is defined in a React Redux reducer file:

```
const initialState = {
    numbers: [
        { name: 'max', num: 3, inCart: false },
        { name: 'jack', num: 2, inCart: true },
        { name: 'jack', num: 2, inCart: true }
    ]
};
```

In a component, I want to sum all the numeric values in all the objects in the numbers array only if  `inCart === true`.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const total = props.numbers.reduce((prev, current) => {
        if (current.inCart) return prev + current.num;
    }, 0);
    console.log(total);
}, []);
```

And this is the console log I get:

```
NaN
```

So it's not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: add an `else`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the updated `prev` at the end inside the `reduce()` method like:

```
const total = props.numbers.reduce((prev, current) => {
  if (current.inCart) prev += current.num;
  return prev;
}, 0);
```

```js
const numbers = [
    { name: 'max', num: 3, inCart: false },
    { name: 'jack', num: 2, inCart: true },
    { name: 'jack', num: 2, inCart: true }
]

const total = numbers.reduce((prev, current) => {
  if (current.inCart) prev += current.num;
  return prev;
}, 0);

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
const total = props.numbers.reduce((prev, current) => {
    return (current.inCart) ? prev + current.num : prev;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return prev when `current.inCart` is `false`.

```
const total = props.numbers.reduce((prev, current) => {
            if (current.inCart) return prev + current.num;
            return prev;  
        }, 0);
```

It should be like this.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce

```
props.numbers.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.inCart ? acc + cur.num : acc, 0);
```

or filter and reduce

```js
const props = {
numbers: [
        { name: 'max', num: 3, inCart: false },
        { name: 'jack', num: 2, inCart: true },
        { name: 'jack', num: 2, inCart: true }
    ]
}
console.log(
  props.numbers
    .filter(item => item.inCart)
    .reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.num, 0)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter out the unnecessary items, and then reduce over the items `inCart` and accumulatively add up `num` property from each object.

```
const initialState = {
    numbers: [
        { name: 'max', num: 3, inCart: false },
        { name: 'jack', num: 2, inCart: true },
        { name: 'jack', num: 2, inCart: true }
    ]
};

initialState.numbers
  .filter(({ inCart }) => inCart)
  .reduce((acc, { num }) => acc += num, 0);
```